# blank elements in Excel: how to fill them as 0 in R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file in Excel to be read into R using the `read.csv` function. However, in the Excel file, some elements are blank, which indicate 0's. When I read the file into R, those elements are still blank. How can I fill these elements as 0's in R? It seems that `is.na`-like functions won't apply to this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the output of a few lines after having read the file into R. The solution could be as simple as `x[x == ""] <- 0` or something similar, but sample data are required to give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: I downvoted because you have some reputation here (so not a new user) and you didn't provide a reproducible example even after Ananda asked for it.  I will remove the downvote if you provide data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on how they're being read in to the R. Blank cells in a numeric column should usually be interpreted as `NA`, in which case

```
your_df$your_column[is.na(your_df$your_column)] <- 0
```

should work. Your question suggests that doesn't work, in which case they might be read in as empty characters. In that case,

```
your_df$your_column[your_df$your_column==""] <- 0
```

ought to do it. If you post a reproducible example (e.g. with a link to the file on Dropbox) it will be possible to be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Like Drew says the way to get NAs from blank is when you read in.  Provide code and example output of the read in data for better responses.  Also play around with `str` as you can see what classes are in the data, which is valuable info.

You may run into some hanky panky (i.e., the data is a factor or character and not a numeric vector) if you have blank cells and the column is numeric.  This approach would address that:

```
## Make up some data
dat <- data.frame(matrix(c(1:3, "", "", 1:3, "", 1:3, rep("", 3), 5), 4))

data.frame(apply(dat, 2, function(x) {
    x[x == ""] <- 0
    as.numeric(x)
}))
```