# Fill NA values with 0 based on columns values

Tags: r, na

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame( V1 = c("A", "B","C","D", "E", "F"), V2 = c(2011,2012,2013,2014, 2015, 2016),V3= c(1,3, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Filling  `NA` values with `0` on `V3` can be easily done, as already discussed here: [blank elements in Excel: how to fill them as 0 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791946/blank-elements-in-excel-how-to-fill-them-as-0-in-r/18792008#18792008). My doubt is how to restrict this operation  to some rows based on values in `V2`. For example, fill `NA` with `O`in `V3`only on rows with values ranging from `2013` to `2015` on `V2`. Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame( V1 = c("A", "B","C","D", "E", "F"), V2 = c(2011,2012,2013,2014, 2015, 2016),V3= c(1,3, 0, 0, 0, NA))
```

Comment: what have you tried yourself? this is a question of basic subsetting in r and  replacing with 0

Comment: taking the linked example, you should add the additional conditions inside the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
df$V3[with(df, is.na(V3) & V2 >= 2013 & V2 <= 2015)] <- 0
```

Thanks to @mtoto for pointing out that the condition `is.na()` should be added.

Comment: it works on the example, but if theres overlap between `NA`'s and the date condition, should add `& is.na(df$V3)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
  if (df$V2[i] %in% c("2013","2014","2015"))
    df$V3[i]<-0
```

Also using the `sqldf` package:

```
df<-sqldf(c("update df set V3=0 where V2 in ('2013','2014','2015')", 
"select * from df "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify column number where you want to replace NA with zeros.

```
df[ df$V2>=2013 & df$V2 <= 2015 & is.na(df$V3),3]=0
```